# RxJava2 (Android): PublishSubject only emits once to activity?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

When publishing to a `PublishSubject`, only the first object published is emitted in my program. A little context of my program:

I have `SomeActivity`, with a `RecyclerView`. In my `Recycler.ViewHolder` I have on click. In the onclick method, I publish an object to the PublishSubject.

In SomeActivity, I subscribe to the PublishSubject in the `onCreate`. When I run my app, I can see that only the first published object is received in SomeActivity. The PublishSubject is wrapped in a simple custom "RxBus" which I use to communicate in my app between different components (Instead of using interfaces etc).

**Here is how I publish in the viewholder:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    RxBus.publish(RxBus.GAME_TOUCHED, new GameEvent(data));
}
```

**Here is how I subscribe in SomeActivity:**

```
RxBus.subscribe(RxBus.GAME_TOUCHED, this, o -> {
        GameEvent gameEvent = (GameEvent) o;
        //Do something here...
    });
```

**Here is my "RxBus":**

```
public final class RxBus {

    private static RxBus INSTANCE;
    private static SparseArray<PublishSubject<Object>> subjectMap = new SparseArray<>();
    private static Map<Object, CompositeDisposable> subscriptionsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static final int GAME_TOUCHED = 7;

    @Retention(SOURCE)
    @IntDef({GAME_TOUCHED})
    @interface Subject {
    }

    private RxBus() {
    }

    public static synchronized RxBus get() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new RxBus();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @NonNull
    private static PublishSubject<Object> getSubject(@Subject int subjectCode) {
        PublishSubject<Object> subject = subjectMap.get(subjectCode);
        if (subject == null) {
            subject = PublishSubject.create();
            subject.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            subjectMap.put(subjectCode, subject);
        }

        return subject;
    }

    @NonNull
    private static CompositeDisposable getCompositeDisposable(@NonNull Object object) {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = subscriptionsMap.get(object);
        if (compositeDisposable == null) {
            compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
            subscriptionsMap.put(object, compositeDisposable);
        }

        return compositeDisposable;
    }

    public static void subscribe(@Subject int subject, @NonNull Object lifecycle, @NonNull Consumer<Object> action) {
        Disposable disposable = getSubject(subject).subscribe(action);
        getCompositeDisposable(lifecycle).add(disposable);
    }

    public static void unregister(@NonNull Object lifecycle) {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = subscriptionsMap.remove(lifecycle);
        if (compositeDisposable != null) {
            compositeDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void publish(@Subject int subject, @NonNull Object message) {
        getSubject(subject).onNext(message);
    }

}
```

In short, subscribe to a certain "eventype" only recieved/emitted once for the activity.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionHolder> {

    private final List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Context context;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QuestionHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        QuestionHolder questionHolder = new QuestionHolder(R.layout.layout_item_question, parent);
        return questionHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(games.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return games.size();
    }

    public void setData(List<Game> newGames){
        games.clear();
        games.addAll(newGames);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        RxBus.publish(RxBus.DELETE_GAME, new GameEvent(games.get(position)));
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //restore view if not/after deleted
    }

    public Context getContext(){
        return context;
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
RxBus.subscribe(RxBus.DELETE_GAME, this, o -> {
            GameEvent gameEvent = (GameEvent) o;
            Game game = gameEvent.getGame();
            MaterialDialog.Builder builder = CustomMaterialDialog.areYouSure("Delete game?", this)
                    .onNegative((dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                    .onPositive((dialog, which) -> {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        viewModel.deleteGame(game);
                    });
            showCustomDialog(builder);
        });
```

**EDIT 3:**

Changes in Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(games.get(position));
    holder.getItemView().setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Game game = holder.getData();
        RxBus.publish(RxBus.GAME_TOUCHED, new GameEvent(game));
    });
}
```

And added this to viewholder:

```
public View getItemView(){
    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: are you trying the bus on "not opened  yet" fragments ?

Comment: @StavroXhardha No, there is no fragments involved. Just one activity, with the recyclerview.

Comment: can you pass the adapter code please ?

Comment: @StavroXhardha I edited my question and added it. I should also say that "RxBus.publish(RxBus.DELETE_GAME, new GameEvent(games.get(position)))" in my adapter, which is another eventtype in my rxbus, does emit more than once for the same activity

Comment: did you try moving the onclick on the `onBindViewHolder()` ?

Comment: are you sure you are subscribing to `RxBus.DELETE_GAME`?

Comment: @StavroXhardha you mean from ViewHolder to Adapter?

Comment: yea try doing that

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, RxBus.DELETE_GAME works, I will edit it in my question. Its RxBus.GAME_TOCUHED that is not working. I removed DELETE_GAME (and some other) from my rxbus intdef to make the question simpler

Comment: @StavroXhardha I did that, still same issue. I added to my question under "Edit 3"

Comment: Any chance that you are calling `unregister` with the same `SomeActivity` object in the dialog you are opening? Also, try to log using `doOnNext` so that you can isolate the problem; you should be able to tell whether (1) Subject is actually receiving the events, (2) subject is emitting the events, or (3) subject is emitting events but subscriber is not receiving them.

Comment: @SanlokLee I was able to locate my problem. I was doing subscribing in the onCreate() in activity. Once I start a new activity, and come back to old activity, subscribe is not recieving any more emitted event. I moved my subscribing to onstart (doing unregister in onstop since earlier ) and now it works as it should.